# Project throwing multiple compilation errors exception

Tags: java, spring, groovy, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I picked up a spring-boot project on ubuntu with intellij 13.0.1 using the gradle build file from spring.io guide. I had some groovy and gradle in my /opt folder but switched to [gvm](http://gvmtool.net/) so my current groovy is :

```
joseph@do-enr-pc-2:~$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.3.6 JVM: 1.8.0_20 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
joseph@do-enr-pc-2:~$ echo $GROOVY_HOME
/home/joseph/.gvm/groovy/current
```

This is a simple project to test how it looks like .All needed files are on [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/9512480)

When I run my project with java I get the following:

```
joseph@do-enr-pc-2:/home/joseph/micro-smpp-client-java$ ./gradlew springBoot && java build/libs/micro-smpp-client-0.1.0.jar --stacktrace
Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "mainClass" on "task ':springBoot'", value: "net.myproject.smpp...".
:springBoot UP-TO-DATE                     

 BUILD SUCCESSFUL

 Total time: 2.813 secs
 Error: Could not find or load main class build.libs.micro-smpp-client-0.1.0.jar
```

But when I run it with groovy I have this following:

```
 joseph@do-enr-pc-2:/home/joseph/micro-smpp-client-java$ ./gradlew springBoot && groovy build/libs/micro-smpp-client-0.1.0.jar --stacktrace
 Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
 Deprecated dynamic property: "mainClass" on "task ':springBoot'", value: "net.myproject.smpp...".
 :springBoot UP-TO-DATE                     

 BUILD SUCCESSFUL

 Total time: 3.934 secs
 org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
 /home/joseph/micro-smpp-client-java/build/libs/micro-smpp-client-0.1.0.jar: 1: unexpected char: 0x5 @ line 1, column 3.
 PK
 ^

 1 error
```

According to my understanding some .class apparently is already present before a possible one generated by my springBoot execution so I renamed the Application.groovy to AppStarter.groovy but it didn't make any difference.

How can this be fixed thanks!!

**EDIT** applying @Dave Syer's Suggestion

after running `./gradlew bootRun` below is what I have as output:

```
 Deprecated dynamic property: "mainClass" on "task ':springBoot'", value:  "net.myproject.smpp.client...".    
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE                    
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE      
:processResources UP-TO-DATE      
:classes UP-TO-DATE      
:findMainClass                 
:bootRun FAILED 

:bootRun FAILED                                     

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
 > No main class specified

 * Try:         
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

After running `/gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/*.jar`  this is what I get:

```
 Deprecated dynamic property: "mainClass" on "task ':springBoot'", value:  "net.myproject.smpp.client...".
 :compileJava UP-TO-DATE                    
 :compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE     
 :processResources UP-TO-DATE      
 :classes UP-TO-DATE      
 :jar                 
 :bootRepackage FAILED          

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRepackage'.
  > Unable to find main class

  * Try:        
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your "springBoot" task is actually doing anything (it's empty). Probably you meant to do this?

```
springBoot {
   mainClass = "net.myproject.smpp.client.Application"
}
```

to configure the Spring Boot plugin, and then

```
$ ./gradlew bootRun
```

or

```
$ ./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

to build a jar and run it.

Edit: and make sure your main class is not in the default package (if you get that right you don't even need to declare it in the springBoot closure as long as there is only one main class in your app).

Comment: I have updated my post with the output of your suggestion. I am definitely not doing something right

Comment: You still have an empty task called "springBoot" (which isn't going to help). I don't think you updated the pastie, so I can't tell what you are doing now.

Comment: Oh right, I think it's a misunderstanding. I thought springBoot task is supposed to be so according to this https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files/issues/3 . Kindly tell me how to either use or not use springBoot task. Thank this is my first spring/gradle project so I am still a little confused

Comment: I'm not sure that issue is relevant (it is marked as resolved and the final version of the [build.gradle](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files/blob/master/complete/build.gradle) works). Maybe you need to share a complete project?

Comment: Hello @Dave Thanks for your time. Please find an sts project at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7n5DCctwtb3ZUxxTGJuMHZUTUk/edit?usp=sharing I have moved to sts and it runs from the sts "Run as Spring Boot App" but doesn't run with command line with gradle wrapper

Comment: Your `Application` class is in the default package (bad idea for all sorts of reasons, but mainly because you can't do package scanning). Fix that and it might work (as long as your springBoot configuration matches where you put it, but leaving it out would also work).

Comment: Can you please update your answer so I mark it correct? I have done a number of things.Updated intellij 13.0 to 13.1,  Started from scratch, put my application.groovy in another package. and it worked